# How to perform randomization of observations into two groups(treatment and placebo) based on categorical variable with >2 levels?

Tags: r

I do have a dataset with participant id and Gender. I want to randomly assign treatment and placebo to male and female participants separately (50% in treatment and 50% in placebo in both group) in the available dataset.

```
dataset<-data.frame("participant ID"=c(1:10), "Gender"=c("M", "F", "M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way.  Since there are 5 obs in each gender group, 2 will be treated and 3 placebo, but you could produce a different result if desired.

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  mutate(rand = runif(n(), 0,1), 
         treatment = case_when(rank(rand) < .5*n() ~ 1, 
                               TRUE ~ 0))
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups:   Gender [2]
#   participant.ID Gender   rand treatment
#            <int> <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1              1 M      0.219          1
# 2              2 F      0.232          0
# 3              3 M      0.811          0
# 4              4 F      0.317          0
# 5              5 M      0.526          1
# 6              6 F      0.303          0
# 7              7 M      0.915          0
# 8              8 F      0.159          1
# 9              9 M      0.831          0
# 10             10 F      0.0400         1
```

The title of your post suggests that one of the variables involved (presumably the `gender` variable in the example above, would have more than two values.  This should work in that setting, too.